Implementing reading users and groups using Microsoft Graph API on my backstage app for the catalog
Please does anyone have experience integrating backstage on Azure. I would like some insights on managing users and groups in catalog.
Using LDAP configuration, the users and groups were successfully implemented but seems a little evasive with Microsoft Graph API.
This is my catalog file
import { 
CatalogBuilder
 } from '@backstage/plugin-catalog-backend';
import { ScaffolderEntitiesProcessor } from '@backstage/plugin-catalog-backend-module-scaffolder-entity-model';
import { Router } from 'express';
import { PluginEnvironment } from '../types';
import { MicrosoftGraphOrgEntityProvider } from '@backstage/plugin-catalog-backend-module-msgraph';

export default async function createPlugin(
    env: PluginEnvironment,
): Promise<Router> {
    const builder = await CatalogBuilder.create(env);
    builder.addProcessor(new ScaffolderEntitiesProcessor());

  try{

    console.log('Env', env)
    console.log('Env config', env.config)
    console.log('Env logger', env.logger)
    console.log('Env schedular', env.scheduler)

    builder.addEntityProvider(
      MicrosoftGraphOrgEntityProvider.fromConfig(env.config, {
        // id: 'msgraph-org',
        logger: env.logger,
        schedule: env.scheduler.createScheduledTaskRunner({
          frequency: { minutes: 60 },
          timeout: { minutes: 15 },
        }),
      }),
    );
  }catch(err) {
    console.log('Error it returns', err);
  }  

  const { processingEngine, router } = await builder.build();
  await processingEngine.start();
  return router;
}

I initially used this setup
import { CatalogBuilder } from '@backstage/plugin-catalog-backend';
import { ScaffolderEntitiesProcessor } from '@backstage/plugin-catalog-backend-module-scaffolder-entity-model';
import { Router } from 'express';
import { PluginEnvironment } from '../types';
import { GroupConfig, LdapOrgEntityProvider, LdapVendor, defaultGroupTransformer } from '@backstage/plugin-catalog-backend-module-ldap';
import { SearchEntry} from 'ldapjs';
import { GroupEntity } from '@backstage/catalog-model';
// import { ScaffolderEntitiesProcessor } from '@backstage/plugin-scaffolder-backend';



export default async function createPlugin(
  env: PluginEnvironment,
): Promise<Router> {
  const builder = await CatalogBuilder.create(env);
  builder.addProcessor(new ScaffolderEntitiesProcessor());

  // The target parameter below needs to match the ldap.providers.target
  // value specified in your app-config.
  builder.addEntityProvider(
    LdapOrgEntityProvider.fromConfig(env.config, {
      id: 'our-ldap-master',
      target: 'ldap://10.1.9.11:389',
      logger: env.logger,
      schedule: env.scheduler.createScheduledTaskRunner({
        frequency: { minutes: 60 },
        timeout: { minutes: 15 },
      }),
      groupTransformer: myGroupTransformer,
    }),
  );


  // builder.addProcessor(new ScaffolderEntitiesProcessor());
  const { processingEngine, router } = await builder.build();
  await processingEngine.start();
  return router;

  
}

export async function myGroupTransformer(
  vendor: LdapVendor,
  config: GroupConfig,
  group: SearchEntry,
): Promise<GroupEntity | undefined> {
 
  const defaultGroupEntity = await defaultGroupTransformer(vendor, config, group);

  // Modify the name field to replace spaces with underscores
  if (defaultGroupEntity && defaultGroupEntity.metadata.name) {
    // defaultGroupEntity.metadata.name = defaultGroupEntity.metadata.name.replace(/['{}()&\s]/g, 'X');
    defaultGroupEntity.metadata.name = defaultGroupEntity.metadata.name.replace(/['{}()&\s]/g, 'X');
    defaultGroupEntity.metadata.name = defaultGroupEntity.metadata.name.replace(/\//g, '_');
  }

  return defaultGroupEntity;
}

and it pulled the users and group as expected.
this is how the types file looks like
import { Logger } from 'winston';
import { Config } from '@backstage/config';
import {
  PluginCacheManager,
  PluginDatabaseManager,
  PluginEndpointDiscovery,
  TokenManager,
  UrlReader,
} from '@backstage/backend-common';
import { PluginTaskScheduler } from '@backstage/backend-tasks';
import { PermissionEvaluator } from '@backstage/plugin-permission-common';
import { IdentityApi } from '@backstage/plugin-auth-node';

export type PluginEnvironment = {
    logger: Logger;
    database: PluginDatabaseManager;
    cache: PluginCacheManager;
  config: Config;
  reader: UrlReader;
  discovery: PluginEndpointDiscovery;
  tokenManager: TokenManager;
  scheduler: PluginTaskScheduler;
  permissions: PermissionEvaluator;
  identity: IdentityApi;
};

